# Getting "Failed to load component" while implementing unit tests in nuxt3 using vitest

Tags: nuxtjs3, vitest

I'm implementing unit tests in nuxt3 using vitest but getting error that component is not loading. Needs guide to implement unit test in nuxt3 using vitest.

Comment: The solution for me was to add ".vue" extension to the file name import